# Retrieve documents in firebase without the id of the collection

Tags: typescript, firebase, nosql

Assuming I have a firebase document tree as follows:

```
Participants --+---member1---+---class1---+---item1--- (data)
               |             |            |---item2--- (data)
               |             |            +---item3--- (data)
               |             |
               |             +---class2---+---item4 --
               |                          +---item5 --
               |
               +---member2---+---class1---+---item6
```

Collections' IDs `class1` and `class2` are known, but documents' IDs `memberx` are auto generated. is it possible to retrieve all `items` of `class1` only without having to also get documents of collections `class2`?
Note that this tree structure assumes that I don't know all IDs of documents members as they were auto-generated, and there are plenty of them

Answer (score 2):

If you're using subcollections, you definitely should read this post: [Understanding Collection Group Queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html)